# how to call a CSS file that exsit in diffrent package in JAVAFX

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I want to call a css file from another package but it wont work, it only work when I place it in the same package, Any help ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In future, please post the code in your question, as [properly formatted text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), as well as the project structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```xml
<stylesheets>
    <URL value="/edu/esprit/outdoors/stylesheet/inscription_fxml.css" />
</stylesheets>
```